# HTML/CSS formatting trouble.

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

So I have made a simple app in ionic and I am formatting my css and html. I am trying to make my app look really nice. All it has right now is a input text field and a input button. I am having a hard time with my margins/padding, not sure. Here is my code:

```css
.title {
    background-color: #e6ffff;
}
input[type=text], select {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    
}

input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

div {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 120px;
    margin-right: 120px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Push Notifications</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
          <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
              <form>
                <input type="text" class="messageText" placeholder="Message" ng-model="messageText">
                <input type="submit" ng-click="submit()">
              </form>      
          </div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
```

[Picture of the app running in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHHIs.png)

See how the gray is all weird and the header also is missing some color? I need some help fixing this. Also I would not mind some css tips on making a app look professional! Thanks in advance!:)

Comment: Open the browser console and look at the box models and applied CSS rules of the elements that aren’t displayed properly.

Comment: I just checked the console and it didn't clear things up for me

Comment: provide a js fiddle pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the problem lies in how you have things positioned in the DOM.
Quickest solution is to add the styles to the form and take a few styles away from the div that's wrapping it.

```
form{
 background:pink;
 background-color: #f2f2f2;
 padding:15px;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
div {
 margin-top: 50px;
 margin-left: 120px;
 margin-right: 120px;
 padding: 15px;
}
```

quick reference for box models: https://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the Answer from @Aldose ... To fix the Header having a margins you can try this.

```
body , html
{
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.title {
  background-color: #e6ffff;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}
```